# External Users with Contribute Permissions are getting Permission Denied Error when Submitting InfoPath List

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, permissions, infopath, error

My company has used InfoPath 2013 to create a form to allow external users to submit issues into a List in SharePoint online. Local domain users (those with company e-mail credentials) can view, submit, edit and otherwise use the InfoPath form without problem.

Those external to the company (our clients), even though they have all the necessary permissions in the SharePoint (Contribute Level) get a permissions denied error when creating a new item on the list or editing an item.

The truly strange thing is, that even though they receive the error, the new item or the edits to the existing item is saved anyway.

My client is extremely frustrated by this, and I have been unable to figure out this problem over the last month. Any and all suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: This could probably happen due to many reasons, but without having personal experience on the issue, I'll give a few ideas to have a look at. 1. Check your site's permission settings and look for any items and repositories (folders, etc.) which have unique permission. E.g. the permission to the InfoPath's default template is probably still required although the actions would work. (So apply site-wide permissions) 2. You probably need to have the "keep me logged in"-setting enabled in your browser. 3. [See](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/36815/21441)

Comment: Finally you can pretty easily replicate the issue by creating your own external account with e.g. your personal email. With the exactly same permissions this should happen to you too. Start by extending the permission for your user to more parent level in your SP hierarchy step by step and eventually you'll hit the level all works.

Answer (score 0):

I have some guesses about your issue:

1. The InfoPath list was created by saved template but external users don’t have enough permissions to perform on the template list.

   Check:
   1) Do all external users have this issue?
   2) Create a new InfoPath form, will the issue occur?
2. Cache issue.

   Test:
   1) Clear browser cache.
   2) Create a new account and test using another machine.

Finally, try to monitor the whole process via Fiddler, see which part causes this issue.

Comment: Thank you for your response Max576. I did audit using fiddler, but I am not familiar with fiddler. I was told by someone who was familiar with fiddler that when the form was submitted it was first reaching out to the root site. Please see this imgur [link](https://imgur.com/dOLTrjs) for the relevent fiddler log.